# How to declare a python c-extension method as a classmethod?

Tags: python, python-c-api

I'm writing a python wrapper for a C++ class that provide several static methods for alternate "constructors". I'm wondering how to export these through the python c-api?

Here is a stub of the relevant C++ code.

```
 PyObject *PyFoo_FromFoo(Foo foo);

 // This should be a class method that create a new instance of PyFoo().
 PyObject *
 PyFoo_Gen1(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
 {
     Foo foo;  // Init this according to args

     return PyFoo_FromFoo(foo);
 }

 static PyMethodDef PyFoo_methods[] = {
    {"Gen1", (PyCFunction)PyFoo_Gen1, METH_VARARGS, "Gen1 foo creator" },
    {NULL}  /* Sentinel */
 };

 PyTypeObject PyFooType = {
   :
   PyFoo_methods, /* tp_methods */
   :
 }

 PyObject *PyFoo_FromFoo(Foo foo)
 {
    PyFoo *v = (PyFoo*)PyObject_New(PyFoo, &PyFooType);
    v->foo = foo;
    return (PyObject*)v;
 }
```

What would be the corresponding of using the `classmethod()` function (directly or through the `@classmethod` decorator) for `Gen1()` in the example above?

Comment: I recommend Cython for interfacing C/C++ with CPython.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting from python 2.3 it can be done using [METH_CLASS](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.METH_CLASS). See [datetime](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/018d353c1c8c87767d2335cd884017c2ce12e045/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L2932) module for a sample.